# URL routing like github using $stateProvider in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm trying to make my routing like github, so xpto.com/ will show home state and xpto.com/:name to show user state.

But it conflicts to each other.

```
$stateProvider
.state('xpto', { url: '', abstract: true })
.state('xpto.home', { url: '/' })
.state('xpto.user', { url: '/:name' });
```

When I hit xpto.com it's trying to show user state.

How can I fix that?

Thanks,
Celso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my mistake.

I'm using browserify and because of that my $stateProvider was splitted into many files causing load in different order, as follow:

```
$stateProvider
.state('xpto', { url: '', abstract: true })
.state('xpto.user', { url: '/:name' })
.state('xpto.home', { url: '/' });
```

Hope that helps somebody.
Cheers.